# Confusion about C++ iterator dereferencing code

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference

I am looking at the following line of code

```
++ptr_it->refcount;
```

where `ptr_it` is an iterator for a list of a particular class where `refcount` is an integer member variable.  I can't figure out whether the `++` operator here is being used to go to the next element of the list in the `ptr_it` or if it is being used to increment the `refcount` variable.  Or maybe both? I figure that `refcount` must be affected in some way otherwise I'm not sure why it is dereferenced here.  Can anyone tell me what is actually happening here.

Comment: Can’t you try it and debug it and see value before and after?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
++ptr_it->refcount;
```

the variable being incremented is `refcount`. There's no ambiguity and no way that more than one thing would be incremented.